# Converting a string that looks like a list into an actual list

Tags: python

I have this string from a file:

```
[u'Some string']
```

I read it as a string in my python script, and I need to convert it back into a list. This looks like a horrible idea, but so far eval seems to work fine:

```
>>> eval("[u'Some string']")
[u'Some string']
>>> type(eval("[u'Some string']"))
<type 'list'>
```

But this seems like a terribly horrible idea. Any way to elegantly do this?

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` does exactly what you want it to

Answer (score 3):

`eval` is unsafe. However, just use `ast.literal_eval`

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = "[u'Some string']"
>>> ast.literal_eval(s)
[u'Some string']
>>>
```

This is safe.